# WordPress Installation transferred to Localhost issue

Tags: wordpress

Maybe this is not a pure programming question.

I moved a copy of the wordpress installation from the webhost and put into my localhost.

And then I opened the web page from the localhost. when I hit the button of Login to Wordpress admin panel, I expect the path would

```
    http://localhost
```

but I got

```
    http://www.mywebhost.com/
```

I don't where I have to changed on the files so everything in the Wordpress would not pointed to my localhost instead of the webhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [official Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) article, it says some steps you need to do when migrating the site like going to the **Administration →  Settings → General** and update the values of **Site address (URL)** and **WordPress Address (URL)**  to the correct domain.

If it doesn't work, you'll need to replace the content of the DB to the new domain.

Comment: or check in table wp_options column option_name = siteurl check the option_value, change http://www.mywebhost.com/ to http://localhost/